# Using reduced mass to solve problems

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, reference-frames

> A small block of mass $m$ rests on the bottom of a big box also of mass $m$. If the small block is then given a velocity $V$ to the right, how far has the box moved once the block has come to rest within the box. The coefficient of friction between the block and box is $\mu$ and all collisions are elastic.

My Attempt:

I tried to solve the question by setting the velocities of both objects equal then finding the acceleration of the box and using kinematics. When I tried to find the acceleration of the box, I thought it would be $\mu mg/m$. The answer says it should be $$\frac{\mu mg}{\frac{m^2}{2m}}$$ aka reduced mass of the system. I assume my method was wrong because of a non-inertial reference frame, but I'm not sure exactly why. Why does using the reduced mass give the correct answer? What does the reduced mass represent in this problem?

Comment: Hello! I have edited your question using MathJax (LaTeX) math typesetting. For future questions, you can refer to [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm a high school student
We use that formula because the box is co-dependant on the block inside it, so we can't look at it as a single-body problem. Everything that affects the block affects the box too, so we can look at it as a one-body problem, plus it's easier than doing extensive math that's required. I hope this help, and if I'm wrong please correct me